# Left/right adjusment of labels in amsrefs

Tags: amsrefs

I am using the LaTeX package amsrefs for bibliography.  The labels in the reference list appear adjusted to the right (of the label column).  Is there a way to make them adjusted to the left?

Here is an example of what I do:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[nobysame,abbrev,alphabetic]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\cite{JS}
\cite{JST}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{JS}{article}{
author={Jones, A.},
author={Smith, B.},
title={A result},
journal={Ann. Math.},
volume={314},
date={2015},
pages={1\ndash1000}
}

\bib{JST}{article}{
author={Jones, A.},
author={Smith, B.},
author={Taylor, C.},
title={Another result},
journal={Ann. Math.},
volume={315},
date={2016},
pages={1000\ndash2000}
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! And thanks for the good MWE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command responsible for this is `\BibLabel`; redefining it by uncommenting `\hfill` will solve the problem, because later the `\bib@mklab` will do `#1\hfil` that pushes the label to the left.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[nobysame,abbrev,alphabetic]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\BibLabel}{%
    %\hfill
    \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.\CurrentBib}\hyper@anchorend}%
    [\thebib]%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\cite{JS}
\cite{JST}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{JS}{article}{
author={Jones, A.},
author={Smith, B.},
title={A result},
journal={Ann. Math.},
volume={314},
date={2015},
pages={1\ndash1000}
}

\bib{JST}{article}{
author={Jones, A.},
author={Smith, B.},
author={Taylor, C.},
title={Another result},
journal={Ann. Math.},
volume={315},
date={2016},
pages={1000\ndash2000}
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}
```

[image]